# react-native-reanimated undefined symbols for architecture arm64 EAS Expo 48 build

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-m1, react-native-reanimated

I recently updated to Expo 48 and now cannot seem to build the iOS version of my app. I was able to build it previously. I am using a Mac with an M1 chip and building on the EAS build server (not locally).

I get the following error:

```
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
┌─ Symbol: hermes::vm::NopCrashManager::~NopCrashManager()
└─ Referenced from:


std::__1::shared_ptr<hermes::vm::CrashManager>::shared_ptr<hermes::vm::NopCrashManager, void>(hermes::vm::NopCrashManager*) in ReanimatedRuntime.o
2631

❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

2632

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried excluding `arm64` in the Excluded Architectures in all pods, the target project, and the RNReanimated pod directly:
[image]

I *can* get the app to run with ExpoGo as long as [react-native-reanimated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated) is using version 2.14.4, However I have tried building with both v2.14.4 and v3.0.2 and get the same error.

Anyone know how to get `react-native-reanimated` building on Expo 48 with an M1 processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using [expo-build-properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/) and changing the `useFrameworks` flag in my app.json to **static** like this:

```
 "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
         {
            "ios": {
               "useFrameworks": "static",
            }
         }
      ],
   ]
}
```

No need to exclude any architectures.